# Use font-awesome with webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, font-awesome

i tried to import fontawesome.scss but it seems like i am doing it in a wrong way. So here what i did:

1. Fist of all, i installed it `npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`
2. Next i configured webpack.config.js with `file-loader`

```js
{
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]',
      outputPath: 'fonts/'
    }
  }]
}
```

3. Tried to import all stuff to my main.scss file

   `$fa-font-path: "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";`

   `@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";`

   `@import "../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";`
4. Then i tried to build `npm run build` and got the errors:

`ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/fa-solid-900.eot' in 'C:\Users\gosto\Documents\project\src\scss'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the npm module is added to the package.json file
2. Look for the package in the node_modules and check whether you have the files in the relative path, you have mentioned.
3. Read the docs for the package [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/getting-started)
4. Follow the way the package is configured & imported in the docs